# How to make the column separator to touch the frame rule?

Tags: lists, enumerate, multicol, rules

I need ot adjust the column seperator line somehow to touch the frame lines which gives a look like table environment.

I was somehow not interested in using tabular environment for this purpose since, the enumeration does not go well with that.(For example, the item numbers are coming in the middle of the table(vertically), not from the top left corner of the table.

### How to achieve this?

So far, I have tried using 
  `framed` environment to get the borders and adjusted the `rule` command to split the frame environment vertically. Now horizontally also I need to split which I am not able to achieve.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\oddsidemargin 0in \evensidemargin 0in \topmargin 0in \textheight 9.2in  \textwidth 6.5in
\usepackage{enumitem, lipsum,xcolor}
\usepackage{framed}
\newlength{\framedline}
\setlength{\framedline}{\textwidth plus 18pt}
\let\oldrule\rule
\renewcommand{\rule}[2]{
   \hspace*{-36.7pt}\oldrule{\framedline}{0.4pt}\newline
}

\usepackage{multicol}
\setlength{\columnseprule}{1pt}

\begin{document}
    \begin{center}\bfseries 
PROGRESS REPORT OF THE PROJECT \\
YEAR: 2015-2017(2 years)
    \end{center}
\begin{framed}
\begin{enumerate}
\item \begin{multicols}{2}
\lipsum[1]
\end{multicols}\rule\\
\item \begin{multicols}{2}
\lipsum[1]
\end{multicols}\rule
\lipsum[1-20]
%
\end{enumerate}
\end{framed} 


\end{document}
```

### My report should like:

[image]

### Current Output:

[image]

Comment: You might have to overlay another line on top.  Actually, you could implement the whole thing using tikzpagenodes and tikzmark.

Answer (score 3):

One approach using `tcolorbox`:

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem} 
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{breakable}

\newtcolorbox{rowtable}[1][]{%
breakable,enhanced,nobeforeafter,colback=white, 
boxsep=1em, after skip=0pt,before skip=-1pt,
arc=0mm,boxrule=1pt, segmentation style={solid,}}

\newtcolorbox{rowcell}[1][]{%
enhanced,nobeforeafter, colback=white, boxsep=1em, 
after skip=0pt,before skip=-1pt,arc=0mm,boxrule=1pt,
left skip=0pt,right skip=0pt, segmentation style={solid,}}

\begin{document}
\sffamily

\begin{tcolorbox}[sidebyside,enhanced,nobeforeafter, 
colback=white, boxsep=1em, after skip=0pt,before skip=-1pt,
arc=0mm,boxrule=1pt,left skip=0pt,right skip=0pt,
segmentation style={solid}]
Date of  start of project: \today 
\tcblower
Total cost of project: \par INR 0,000,000.00
\end{tcolorbox}
\begin{rowtable}
\section{foo}
\begin{enumerate}
\item \lipsum[1]
\begin{enumerate}
\item \lipsum[2]
\item \lipsum[3]
\end{enumerate}
\tcbline \item \lipsum[4]
\tcbline \item \lipsum[5]
\tcbline \item \lipsum[6-7]
\tcbline \item \lipsum[8]   
\end{enumerate}
\end{rowtable}
\begin{rowtable}
\section{Some more} \lipsum[9]  
\end{rowtable}
\begin{tcbraster}[raster columns=3,raster equal height,raster equal skip=-2pt]
\begin{rowcell} This    \end{rowcell}%
\begin{rowcell}  is \end{rowcell}%
\begin{rowcell}The end \end{rowcell}%
\end{tcbraster}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Its awesome... Only one place i had an issue with the boxes, that is, in the last 3 column box, if i want to enumerate those cells(ofcourse inside), the boxes are moving right ward.@Fran